# Door hardware need to replace

Tags: doors, lock

I need to replace this door hardware but not sure how or where to search. I have checked eBay but  there are so many and hard to know what one for sure will work . Any help would be great.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The name is on it look for a Corbin latch a quick look I found one but it was almost as expensive as a new lock set with a latch. Shopping help is off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to any hardware store or one of the big box stores (orange or blue) and they will fix you up.

Comment: A great example of why shopping questions are off-topic.

Comment: To be clear, the big box store will sell you a new doorknob, not a Corbin latch assembly. One might be lucky enough to find a sympathetic individual behind the counter of a specialty door place that could match the Corbin.